# Xcode error 100021

Tags: xcode, osx-mountain-lion

Today, I added a small piece of functionality (a few lines of code only, everything else is identical) to an app that I want to publish on the Mac App Store.

This is an app that is already on the store, and the only change I've made is in the code itself, so publishing should work exactly as before, but this being Xcode we're talking about, it came up with this error:

[image]

And nothing else. This happens when I go to the Archive Manager, and try to go through the Distribute... dialog. Any ideas on how to debug this and/or what did Xcode screw up? This is the latest Xcode (4.6.1) on the latest OS X (10.8.3).

Comment: @Viral: looked at that, but that didn't help (also this is a Mac app, not an iOS app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More of a clue than an answer here, but I ran into the same problem and it turned out to be because of symbolic links copied into the app from a "Copy Files" build step.

However, in my case I'd just tried to bundle in the Nvidia Cg library and had added a "Copy Files" entry to copy the framework.  Hence the culprit was obvious: the Cg.framework directory has a bunch of symbolic links.  Whether it was a good and proper solution I don't know, but I simply changed my "Copy Files" to copy only the code library itself.

```
Copy Files
Destination: Frameworks
Subpath: Cg.framework
Cg in sdk/cg/Cg.framework/Versions/1.0
```

Hopefully this will help somebody who ends up here searching for error code 100021.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I fixed it by deleting the *.framework items in the Copy Bundle Resources list under Build Phases that you see by clicking on the project name. These frameworks had already been added to the project files list that you normally see on the far left.